# Moving method from derived class to base

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

I've some classes (`Derived1`, `Derived2`, etc.) derived from class `Base`. All of derived classes have a following methods (reduced sample):

```
void Derived1::handleTimer(const StatusType &st) {
  if (!st.isOk()) {
    m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(10); // wait for 10 seconds;
    m_timer->SetHandler(boost::bind(Derived1::handleTimer, this, _1));
    return;
  }

  try {
    ... // there is some specific for Derived's code
    m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(10 * 60); // wait for 10 minutes;
    m_timer->SetHandler(boost::bind(Derived1::handleTimer, this, _1));
  }
  catch(...) {
    m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(10); // wait for 10 second;
    m_timer->SetHandler(boost::bind(Derived1::handleTimer, this, _1));
  }
}

void Derived1::start() {
  m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(1); // wait for 1 second;
  m_timer->SetHandler(boost::bind(Derived1::handleTimer, this, _1));
}
```

I'd like to move these methods to `Base`. However, my trying looks pretty ugly. Is there more appropriate way? 
There is my current solution.

```
class Base {
public:
  typedef boost::function <void (const StatusType&)> HandlerType;
  Base(HandlerType handler) : m_hadler(handler) {}
  void start() {
    m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(1); // wait for 1 second;
    m_timer->SetHandler(m_handler);
  }
protected:
  virtual void doSomeSpecific() = 0;

  void handleTimer(const StatusType &st) {
    if (!st.isOk()) {
      m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(10); // wait for 10 seconds;
      m_timer->SetHandler(m_handler);
      return;
    }

    try {
      doSomeSpecific();
      m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(10 * 60); // wait for 10 minutes;
      m_timer->SetHandler(m_handler);
    }
    catch(...) {
      m_timer->WakeUpPeriod(10); // wait for 10 second;
      m_timer->SetHandler(m_handler);
    }
  }

private:
  HandlerType m_handler;

  ... // other data and function members
};
```

Now `Derived` classes

```
void Derived1::doSomeSpecific() { ... }

Derived1::Derived1() : Base(boost::bind(Derived1::handleTimer, this, _1) {}

void Derived1::handleTimer(const StatusType &st) { Base::handleTimer(st); }
```

Comment: Why would the derived classes have to override `handleTimer()`? Couldn't they just inherit it?

Comment: Why do you call `AsynWait` on `Derived1::handleTimer` inside `Derived1::handleTimer` itself? This looks like an endless recursion to me.

Comment: @Andris - Looks like I obfuscate code trying to make sample. Thank you. See update

Answer (score 5):

The use of `doSomeSpecific` inside of `handleTimer` is remarkably similar to the [Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

If there is no base implementation of `doSomeSpecific` you might consider making it private (still virtual so it can be overridden). Unless of course you really want further derived classes to be able to call the `doSomeSpecific` implementations of their parent classes.

Also, you can consider making `handleTimer` non-virtual if all derived classes must have the same behavior.

By making `doSomeSpecific` private, and `handleTimer` non-virtual, the only point of customization becomes `doSomeSpecific`, and it becomes an all or nothing point of customization. This can simplify your implementations of your derived classes, because you can trust that they only customize one specific part of your base class.